Visa for Jersey: Do I need an ETA?
am planning to go to Jersey for 2 weeks as a tourist, I am holding a passport from Spain...
So, since this new ETA for UK is coming (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/apply-for-an-electronic-travel-authorisation-eta)
visiting the  jersey official page here:
https://www.gov.je/Travel/InformationAdvice/Visitors/pages/visapassportrequirements.aspx
I can read:

The Jersey visa requirements are aligned to the UK visa requirements.
Find out if you need a UK visa on the GOV Uk website. Schengen visas
are not valid in Jersey.
EEA and Swiss nationals are among a number of nationals who don't
require a visa to visit Jersey for up to 6 months.

So my question, Do I need an ETA?

When are you planning to go?
ETAs will be required for Spanish citizens from 2 April 2025.
If you intend to travel before that you don't need one, your passport is enough.
If you intend to travel or or after that date, you will be able to apply from 5 March 2025.
